# Recursively Assign to Variable Slices in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, variables, slice, assign

I want to recursively assign values to slices in a Tensorflow (1.15) variable.

To illustrate, this works:

```
    def test_loss():

        m = tf.Variable(1)
        n = 3

        A = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10., 20., 30.]))
        B = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10., 20., 30.]))
        A = A[m+1:n+1, 10:12, 20:22].assign(B[m:n, 2:4, 3:5])

        return 1

    test_loss()
    Out: 1
```

Then I tried:

```
    def test_loss():

        m = tf.Variable(1)
        #n = 3

        A = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10., 20., 30.]))
        B = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10., 20., 30.]))

        for n in range(5):
            A = A[m+1:n+1, 10:12, 20:22].assign(B[m:n, 2:4, 3:5])

        return 1

    test_loss()
```

But this returns an error message:

```
    ---> 10         A = A[m+1:n+1, 10:12, 20:22].assign(B[m:n, 2:4, 3:5])
    ...
    ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables
```

I understood that what 'assign' returns is not a 'Variable', therefore in the next loop pass 'A' will
not find a 'Variable' anymore.

Then I tried:

```
    def test_loss():

        m = tf.Variable(1)
        #n = 3

        A = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10., 20., 30.]))
        B = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10., 20., 30.]))

        for n in range(5):
            A = tf.Variable(A[m+1:n+1, 10:12, 20:22].assign(B[m:n, 2:4, 3:5]))

        return 1

    test_loss()
```

And then I got:

```
    InvalidArgumentError: Input 'ref' passed float expected ref type while building NodeDef...
```

Any idea please about I could recursively assign values to Tensorflow variable slices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some insights to using `tf.Variable` and `assign()`.

### First solution that failed

```
for n in range(5):
            A = A[m+1:n+1, 10:12, 20:22].assign(B[m:n, 2:4, 3:5])
```

When you do `A.assign(B)`, it in fact returns a tensor (i.e. not a `tf.Variable`). So it works on the first iteration. From next iteration onwards, you are trying to assign values to a `tf.Tensor`, which is not allowed.

### Second solution that failed

```
for n in range(5):
            A = tf.Variable(A[m+1:n+1, 10:12, 20:22].assign(B[m:n, 2:4, 3:5]))
```

This is again a pretty bad idea, because you're creating variables within a loop. Do this enough and you'll run out of memory. But this wouldn't even run, because you have ended up with a funky deadlock. You are trying to create variable with some tensor that will be computed when the Graph executes. And to execute the graph, you need the variables.

### Correct way to do this

The best way I can think of doing this would be for `test_loss` to return the update operation and you make `n` a TensorFlow placeholder. And at each iteration when running the session, you pass a value to `n` (which is the current iteration).

```
def test_loss(n):

        m = tf.Variable(1)
        #n = 3

        A = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10., 20., 30.]))
        B = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10., 20., 30.]))

        update = A[m+1:n+1, 10:12, 20:22].assign(B[m:n, 2:4, 3:5])        

        return update

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf_n = tf.placeholder(shape=None, dtype=tf.int32, name='n')
    update_op = test_loss(tf_n)
    print(type(update_op))
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for n in range(5):
      print(1)
      #print(sess.run(update_op, feed_dict={tf_n: n}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It feels to me that in this case, using PyTorch is a better paradigm (more "pythonic").

Comment: I agree if you have dynamic operations you can go with Pytorch. But you can give TF2 a try too. They moved to eager execution meaning that tensors are executed immediately.